# Менеджер буфера обмена

Tags: android

На Андроиде накидать в буфер обмена разных текстов и что бы потом по вызову функции вставить можно было выбрать один из них. То есть менеджер буфера обмена. Подскажите пожалуйста в какую сторону копать или хотя бы где можно посмотреть. Интересует как расширить возможности функции Вставить.

Comment: В гугловкой клавиатуре есть буфер обмена

Comment: [ClipboardManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ClipboardManager?hl=ru)